# How to Connect Openedge to Crystal Report

Tags: openedge, crystal-reports-2010, progress-db

has anyone tried Connecting Openedge 11.1 or 11.7 to Crystal Reports? If so, what version of Crystal Reports should I use? Hoping someone will help. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In general such open ended questions are frowned upon here. It's better to ask a specific question showing what you've tried and why it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports wants a SQL connection to the OpenEdge database.

If your client is a Windows client and has Progress installed on it the ODBC/JDBC drivers should already exist.  If you do not have Progress already installed the drivers are a free download from progress.com:

https://www.progress.com/odbc/openedge

https://www.progress.com/faqs/datadirect-odbc-faqs/progress-database-odbc-and-jdbc-driver-faq

If the OpenEdge DB has been configured to permit SQL access you will need to work with the OpenEdge DBA to obtain the connection details:  hostname, port, username, and password so that you can create the appropriate connection configuration within Crystal.

If the OpenEdge DB is not currently configured to support SQL queries the DBA will need to add that capability and then provide you with the credentials.

If the database is provided as part of a 3rd party application you may need to work with the vendor to get that setup.